# Using event.target with React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having some trouble with my project. Can anyone explain to me why I can't use the `e.target` to access anything other than `className`?

Below is the code from my entry point:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Button from './Button'
import Menu from './Menu'

function test(e){
    console.log(e.target.ref)
 }

module.exports = class Content extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={content: ''}
    }

update(e){
    console.log(e.target.txt)

}

render (){
    return (
        <div id="lower">
            <div id="menu">
               <Menu onClick={this.update.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                {this.state.content}
            </div>
        </div>
    )

  }
}
```

I am trying to access the setting in the **Menu** component, using the `update` method. See **Menu** below:

```
module.exports = class Menu extends React.Component {

    render (){
       return (
           <div>
               <Button space="home" className="home" txt="Home" onClick={this.props.onClick}/>

        </div>
       )

    }
}
```

I really want to know why I can access the `txt` and `space` value using `e.target`. I have read the documentation and looked for other sources but I have no answer yet, but I am hoping there is a way it can be done.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

First argument in `update` method is [`SyntheticEvent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) object that contains common properties and methods to any [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), it is not reference to React component where there is property `props`.

if you need pass argument to update method you can do it like this

```
onClick={ (e) => this.props.onClick(e, 'home', 'Home') }
```

and get these arguments inside `update` method

```
update(e, space, txt){
   console.log(e.target, space, txt);
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44564/)

---

`event.target` gives you the native `DOMNode`, then you need to use the regular DOM APIs to access attributes. For instance `getAttribute` or `dataset`

```
<button 
  data-space="home" 
  className="home" 
  data-txt="Home" 
  onClick={ this.props.onClick } 
/> 
  Button
</button>

onClick(e) {
   console.log(e.target.dataset.txt, e.target.dataset.space);
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44566/)

Comment: What is the 'target'? Why can't I use event.dataset?

Comment: It's an `EventTarget` which has an extremely limited interface:

Comment: I meant `SyntheticEventTarget`