# Get column name from row mapping with onClick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this reactjs app I have a table with the following body:

```
            <tbody>
                {results.map(result =>
                    <tr key={result.metric} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t00}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t01}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t02}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t03}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t04}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t05}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t06}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t07}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t08}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t09}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t10}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t11}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t12}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t13}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t14}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t15}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t16}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t17}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t18}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t19}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t20}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t21}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t22}</td>
                        <td className="inpt-td">{result.t23}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
```

The header does not exist for this particular table, but I was wondering if there was a way to obtain the column name of a clicked cell. So for example if you clicked on the second cell in a given row, it would return "t01", which is the column name.

My searches online did not provide an efficient way of doing this. Is there a method to retrieve this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `handleClick` you can get access to the `event.target` property, which is a `cell`.

After that you can do:

```
var child = event.target;
var parent = child.parentNode;
// equivalent of parent.children.indexOf(child)
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(parent.children, child);
var value = 't' + index // this will be value what you are looking for
```

If you need information how to use `event.target` - here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639122/using-event-target-with-react-components).

Comment: wow I can't believe I didn't think of that. Glad I named my columns that way to be able to have that kind of solution. Thanks for your help