# React onChange function. Nothing is getting passed like event?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a react tutorial and I see this code:

[image]

So I guess we need to just supply a function to the `onChange` field... not actually call it. That's why we don't need to pass `event` to the function when it itself is being passed to `onChange` right? What is `onChange` called btw? Does it have a name in `react`?

I guess whatever function we pass to `onChange`, React attempts to pass the event to it right?

Comment: onChange event handler has event as parameter, but the event here is referring to synthetic event, it has no target.value,check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639122/using-event-target-with-react-components

Comment: You are correct in that you are passing the function instead of calling it. The React docs have more information about using functions in this manner: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Basically React creates its own SyntheticEvent wrapper over original event (it has almost the same API as original one) and passes it to your event handler as first argument. Also you are correct about passing a function without calling it, React will call it for you on event.