# Change prop of child component when s

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm building my site with Gatsby and I'm trying to change the URL prop of the Plyr component when a user clicks on a lesson title. Right now the URL is set in the `this.state` with data pulling from a GraphQL query to Contentful.

Here's a live version: https://brave-jepsen-d8ae28.netlify.com/courses/my-first-course

I created a handleChange function to set the state with the `event.target.id`, but it's returning errors once I click on a lesson paragraph tag. Any idea what's going on? I tested that the event Id was being captured with a `console.log(event.target.id)`, and it was, so I'm assuming it's something with rendering the component again once I attempt to set the state.

Any help is appreciated!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Layout from '../components/layout' 
import Plyr from 'react-plyr'
import '../components/plyr.css'

// On click, set the value of that elements video url to video player url value

class CourseTemplate extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            url: props.data.contentfulCourse.featureVideo
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    };

    handleChange(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // console.log(event.target.id)
        this.setState(prevState => ({
             url: event.target.id
        }));
      }

    render() {
        const courseContent = this.props.data.contentfulCourse
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Plyr key={this.state.url} type="vimeo" videoId={this.state.url}/>
            <p>{this.state.url}</p>
            <h1>{courseContent.title}</h1>
            <p>{courseContent.shortDescription}</p>
            <div>
                {courseContent.teachers.map(teacher => (
                    <div key={teacher.id}>
                        <p>by <Link to={`/teachers/${teacher.id}`}>{teacher.name}</Link></p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div>
                {courseContent.lessons.map(lesson => (
                    <div key={lesson.lessonVideo}>
                        <p onClick={this.handleChange} id={lesson.lessonVideo}>{lesson.title}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </Layout>   
    )
    }
};

export default CourseTemplate

export const query = graphql`
  query CourseTemplate($id: String!) {
    contentfulCourse(id: {eq: $id}) {
      title
      shortDescription
      featureVideo
      slug
      teachers {
        id
        name
      }
      lessons {
        id
        title
        lessonVideo
        slug
      }
    } 
  }
`
```

Errors I'm receiving:

`Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property 'target' on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null at ProxyComponent.eval`

Comment: "it's returning errors once I click" - can you show us the errors?

Comment: I added a live example on https://brave-jepsen-d8ae28.netlify.com/courses/my-first-course, and I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

On localhost I'm getting a longer error 
`synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `target` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()` plus the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using event.target with React components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639122/using-event-target-with-react-components) - your issue is caused by Synthetic Events used by React. `this.setState` is asynchronous so by the time `event.target.id` is called `event.target` can no longer be safely accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `event` at all for this. You also don't need to pass a function to `setState` since you're not doing anything with `prevState`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Plyr from "react-plyr"
import "../components/plyr.css"

class CourseTemplate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      url: props.data.course.featureVideo,
    }
    this.setVideoUrl = this.setVideoUrl.bind(this)
  }

  setVideoUrl(url) {
    this.setState({ url })
  }

  render() {
    const courseContent = this.props.data.course

    return (
      <Layout>
        <Plyr type="vimeo" videoId={this.state.url} />

        <div>
          {courseContent.lessons.map(lesson => (
            <div key={lesson.id}>
              <p onClick={() => this.setVideoUrl(lesson.videoUrl)}>
                {lesson.title}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default CourseTemplate

export const query = graphql`
  query CourseTemplate($id: String!) {
    course: contentfulCourse(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      shortDescription
      featureVideo
      slug
      teachers {
        id
        name
      }
      lessons {
        id
        title
        videoUrl: lessonVideo
        slug
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick! I was getting issues with the Plyr component that I was using, so I switched to another react-player library and got it to work!