# How to handle events on the extra space in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

How to handle the events when someone clicks(mouse click) on the violet color space around the elements ?
Putting a general onclick on the container is overriding the individual item behaviors (they all have their internal onclick handlers). Any other way to solve this ?

[image]

Edit:

```html
<Grid onClick={ClickHandler} container direction="row">
  <Grid item>
    // Filter Screen that has buttons, checkboxes
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    ............
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The problem here is the container ClickHandler just overrides all the clickhandlers that the filter screen has. So that tactic was not successful.

Comment: Cold you provide enough code for us to see the problem. I don't understand how the event listeners are being overridden.

Comment: Just added the code, let me know if I need to add to add more to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring; for instance, clicks on checkboxes are still processed.

```jsx
<Grid onClick={ClickHandler} container direction="row">
  <Grid item onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
    // Filter Screen that has buttons, checkboxes
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    ............
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That works well, I didnt know about this method. Reading up on it now.

Comment: if it worked for you make sure to mark it as correct please and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that I think will work, but I'm not sure is the best approach or follows best practices. I would make use of the [`data-` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639122/using-event-target-with-react-components) on your components. Add an attribute like `data-element="container"` to your parent container. If `event.target.dataset.element === "container"` in your click handler, then you've clicked the background around the elements, otherwise you've clicked one of the elements. If necessary, you can also add `data-element="componentN"` to each of your components inside the container and move your logic for the `onClick` effects for your individual components inside there.

Comment: Looks interesting, I havent tried this, the below one works for me, this definitely feels logical.